# Where to find 'application.log'?

Tags: playframework

I've enabled production mode logging in Play! and I'm using this configuration from here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/production

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Rolling

log4j.logger.play=INFO

# Rolling files
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=application.log
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

When I run the app with `play run` where is `application.log` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this config, it will be in the working directory of the application. It's maybe easier and more deterministic to put an absolute path in there.

Comment: I need to deploy this app on a remote tomcat server, can I still use absolute path?

Comment: Use absolute or relative to the working directory I use the following which puts the file in the application/logs directory:  <param name="File" value="logs/myapp.log" />